# comparing Pearson Correlation of 2 samples against a rating sample set

Tags: correlation

I am analyzing a survey result. I have 2 factors 1) a trainer factor 2) a participant benefited factor. These 2 factors are compared against a training rating and correlation is calculated. can i compare the (r)s? i.e., (r) of trainer factor to rating and (r) of participant factor to rating

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the difference between correlation coefficients can be tested for statistical significance. The test statistic depends on the two $r$ values, as well as on the sizes of the samples involved, $n_1$ and $n_2$. The exact formula depends on whether the correlation coefficients were calculated in the same group or not; and if they come from the same group, on whether they share a common variable or not. In $R$, the `cocor` package handles all these situations conveniently. See the related publication: [Diedenhofen & Musch 2015](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0121945)

Comment: Sample size is same.For example: (r)of sample x->A is .6 and (r)of sample y->A is .4; can i have a method to tell that Sample x is more correlated to A by a factor, as compared to sample y, and the significance of this deviation???

Comment: I think you mean variables rather than factors. Can you specify a bit what these variables are? More specifically, are values of $x$ and $y$ paired somehow? (e.g. related to the same individual or item)